# How to hold down a join in an engineered wood floor

Tags: engineered-flooring

I've inherited this floor which has an annoying seam five planks wide where the wood on either side is a few mm different in height, and the door catches on it.

If I stand on one side, my weight is enough to even it out, but I need some way to hold it down without spoiling the look or taking it all up.

I am thinking two very thin slivers of something glued on either side, squeezed into the gaps and leave a pile of books on it until the glue sets. Not sure the best things to buy, or any better suggestions?[image][image]

Comment: add a picture, what is 5 planks wide (5 plank lengths wide, 5 plank widths wide?).  doors are typically installed with 1/2" gap between bottom of door and floor for air flow, how much is this hump sticking up?  there are some youtube videos with people drilling the join area and using turkey baster to inject glue under low plank.  i've used support rods against floor and ceiling to hold down high plank and tape and block to get boards to join.

Answer (score 1):

Engineered wood floors don't normally have 'gaps', they're tongue & groove, click to fit. As such you'll not get glue to squeeze between them.
They should also be laid onto an intermediate 'soft' layer, a kind of underlay for planks, so they don't sit directly on the substrate floor. This would preclude gluing too.

Your idea to shim & glue would likely just lift the surrounding planks, as there's nothing else to keep them flat except their joint weight.

First check would be to see if they're cut short enough. Lift the quarter-round or skirting as appropriate where they meet the walls & check enough space was left that they don't squeeze against the walls when warm or damp. If they do, you'll have to lift them to shorten them. If they're not properly interlocked that shouldn't be too hard to do. If they are, you'll have to start from one edge.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. I've now figured out how to add pictures, after finding compression software. It's 5 plank widths wide, and the join is something you wouldn't usually see in a floor like this, but it occurs in this single place on the floor, I'm not sure why. The level difference is about 5mm. I'm not sure I understand the advice too well; I need the floor level to go to the lower level rather than the higher level, and ideally not end up with visible screw holes.

Comment: Ach… they put a butt-joint half way across the floor. They are interlocked planks, but not when you install them like that, they should have been lapped like layers of brick. There should be a place in hell reserved for doing it like that, but unfortunately you will have to suffer it:\ If you glue one to the other, then apart from trying to glue 'underlay' which will simply not work, the law of murphy says the upwardly-bowed ones will lift the straight ones, not lower the bent ones. What's your substrate? I'd be looking at screwing it down if you have wood under there.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply. The floor is on the first floor, so the floor structure below is timber joists. How would I know where the joists are to screw into, and how would I avoid unsightly screw heads? The house is only 20 years old and I have the floor plans, but scaling off those would be very unreliable. The joists are about 400 centres. I'd rather not create multiple holes trying to locate the joists, nor would I want to lift the floor. Would it need sunken screw heads with a wood filler on top? Would spoil the look of the floor ...

Comment: I just tried poking a kitchen knife down the butt joint where it's wide enough. In all cases, the knife goes down about a centimeter then stops. Maybe the entire joint is on the line of a joist, that would be good! Seems logical as the joint is on the wall line where it joins the stairwell....

Comment: I'd go with some PVA injected into the crack, as you imply there's no underlay [not really a surprise considering what a botch-job the rest of it is ;) & one countersunk screw, the depth of your plank as measured by the knife plus 10mm, not placed anywhere 'mathematically perfect' . Fill the hole. In 6 months you'll forget it was a screw & think it's a knot.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. I really appreciate it. I hope you have a fantastic Christmas.